# Save the data and go to the previous view by clicking the send button in keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios5

I have a **signup** page and once I am done with entering my details in signup, I want to click a send button in the keyboard(inplace of **return** key). It *should save all the data in the signup page and take me to the previous login page*.

For **username** and **email** textfields, i've used the **next** button, so that it *switches the tabs* once I am done with each of the textfields. It is working fine.

So, when i click the next button on the email textfield's keyboard, it takes me to the password textfield and once I am done with entering the password, the send button in the keyboard is visible. But when i try to click it, **no action** is performed.

So, if i click on the send button, it should **save all the data that I've entered in the signup page and should take me to the previous login page.** Acting like a normal submit button, i want the **send button in the keyboard** to perform the action rather than the other normal buttons.

This is my code for send and next keyboard buttons in the signup page,

```
-(IBAction)send
{

    NSUserDefaults *stringDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [stringDefault setValue:@"" forKey:@"stringKey"];
    [stringDefault setValue:name.text forKey:@"Username"];
    [stringDefault setValue:email.text forKey:@"EmailID"];
    [stringDefault setValue:password.text forKey:@"password"];
    [stringDefault synchronize];
    NSLog(@"%@",name.text);
    //   NSLog(@"%@",email.text);`
    // NSLog(@"%@",password.text);
    NSString *emailRegEx = @"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx];
    //Valid email address
    if ([emailTest evaluateWithObject:email.text] == NO) 
    {
        UIAlertView *Alt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Incorrect" message:@"Enter a valid email id" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [Alt show];
        [Alt release];
        NSLog(@"email not in proper format");

    }
    NSString *passwordd = @"[A-Za-z]{8,12}";
    NSPredicate *passtest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", passwordd];
    //Valid email address
    if ([passtest evaluateWithObject:password.text] == NO) 
    {   
        UIAlertView *Alt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Incorrect" message:@"Enter a valid password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [Alt show];
        [Alt release];
        //  NSLog(@"email not in proper format");

    }

    login *l=[[login alloc]initWithNibName:@"login" bundle:nil];

    [self presentModalViewController:l animated:YES];

   }


-(IBAction)next:(UITextField *)ras{
        if (ras == name) {
            [ras resignFirstResponder];
            [email becomeFirstResponder];
        } 
        else if (ras == email) {
            [ras resignFirstResponder];
            [password becomeFirstResponder];
        }
        else if (ras == password) {
            [ras resignFirstResponder];
        }
        //return YES;
    }
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: are you want store only one user data or multiple UserDeta...?

Comment: only one user at a time during signup. But multiple users will be having their respective accounts if they register with my app.

Comment: for single user you can manage with NSuserDefoult but if you create for Multiuser you can must have be use Sqlite database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

send property UIReturnType to UIReturnTypeSend of UITextField and set delegate

```
[usernameTextField setReturnType:UIReturnTypeSend];
[usernameTextField setDelegate:self];
[passwordTextField setReturnType:UIReturnTypeSend];
[passwordTextField setDelegate:self];
```

then use then textFieldDelegateMethod ShouldReturn

```
-(BOOL)validationSuccess{

    NSString *emailRegEx = @"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";

    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx];

    //Valid email address
    if ([emailTest evaluateWithObject:email.text] == NO)
    {
        UIAlertView *Alt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Incorrect" message:@"Enter a valid email id" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [Alt show];
        [Alt release];
        NSLog(@"email not in proper format");

        return NO;

    }
    NSString *passwordd = @"[A-Za-z]{8,12}";
    NSPredicate *passtest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", passwordd];
    //Valid email address
    if ([passtest evaluateWithObject:password.text] == NO)
    {
        UIAlertView *Alt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Incorrect" message:@"Enter a valid password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [Alt show];
        [Alt release];
        //  NSLog(@"email not in proper format");

        return NO;

     }

    return YES;

}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    if([self validationSuccess])
    {
        //Save your data here

        [self saveData];

        //If you have pushed from loginviewcontroller then you can go back directly

        [[self navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

        //Or if you have presented from loginviewcontroller

         [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    }

    return YES;
}

-(void)saveData{

    NSUserDefaults *stringDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [stringDefault setValue:@"" forKey:@"stringKey"];
    [stringDefault setValue:name.text forKey:@"Username"];
    [stringDefault setValue:email.text forKey:@"EmailID"];
    [stringDefault setValue:password.text forKey:@"password"];
    [stringDefault synchronize];

}
```

Comment: Hi, can u tell me where i've to write that 1st 4 lines of code that u've suggested? "send property UIReturnType to UIReturnTypeSend of UITextField and set delegate"

Comment: in viewdidload or you can change properties by interface builder

Comment: The code is correct. But how to give action to the send button? When i click send, even with ur code, its not working.

Comment: u dont need to create another action for send button action you can write your send button code inside textFieldShouldReturn as i have mentioned (when you click on send button then textFieldShouldReturn method will call)

Comment: login *l=[[login alloc]initWithNibName:@"login" bundle:nil];

    [self presentModalViewController:l animated:YES]; and -(IBAction)next:(UITextField *)ras . Do i have to write both these codes also inside the textfield should return method?

Comment: @abishek: I've tried writing all those down inside the textfieldshouldReturn also. Still there is no action from the send button.

Comment: did you set delegate of uitextfield ?

Comment: Where exactly i have to set them?

Comment: @abishek: You've noticed this method "-(IBAction)next:(UITextField *)ras" right? I've written this method  outside the -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn. Is that fine?

Comment: in view did load set delegate of uitextfield to self and copy code from next methods and paste inside textefieldsouldreturn if it will not work then let me know i will try to send you sample code.